# Get value of nested variable name in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a subroutine which uses parameter to return a string. As part of my logging I want to display the returned parameter value before I exit the routine.

Easier to explain in code!

```
@ECHO OFF
SET MYVAL=1
ECHO Before MYVAL=%MYVAL%
CALL :SETMYVAL MYVAL
ECHO After  MYVAL=%MYVAL%
PAUSE
EXIT /b 0

:SETMYVAL
SET "%~1=2"
ECHO SETMYVAL called, returning %~1=%~1
GOTO :EOF
```

The above code produces:

```
Before MYVAL=1
SETMYVAL called, returning MYVAL=MYVAL
MYVAL=2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

But I want the last line ofthe subroutine to output

```
SETMYVAL called, returning MYVAL=2
```

Any ideas (without moving the line, or using extensions or delayed expansion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ECHO SETMYVAL called, returning %~1=2
```

This should do it....

Or

```
ECHO SETMYVAL called, returning %~1=%MYVAL%
```

or

```
call ECHO SETMYVAL called, returning %~1=%%%~1%%
```

Comment: lol, the first 2 would work but don't really help me! but I'm afraid the last one didn't though :-)

Comment: The last one works for me.Are you you have the `call` in front and the exact numbers of `%`-es ?

Comment: Yeah, I pasted it in, 3%'s before and 2 after. Do you have extensions on?

Comment: Sorry npocmaka, I didn't have the 'call' in front :-( answers my question perfectly, so you'd better have the tick. Sorry foxidrive

Answer (score 1):

Your case is artificial, so you may not get a real life solution.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET MYVAL=1
ECHO Before MYVAL=%MYVAL%
CALL :SETMYVAL MYVAL
ECHO After  MYVAL=%MYVAL%
PAUSE
EXIT /b 0

:SETMYVAL
SET "val=2" & call SET "%~1=%%val%%"
ECHO SETMYVAL called, returning %~1=%val%
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Brilliant, that works a treat. Good bit of lateral thinking :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks foxidrive, the best I could come up with is:

```
:SETMYVAL
SET "%~1=2"
ECHO ECHO %%%~1%%>"%TEMP%\SETMYVAL.bat"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('CALL "%TEMP%\SETMYVAL.bat"') DO (CALL :SETMYVALFROMFILE %%A)
ECHO SETMYVAL called, returning %~1=%MYTEMP%
GOTO :EOF
:SETMYVALFROMFILE
SET MYTEMP=%~1
GOTO :EOF
```

Nasty eh?